# Gulp task runs once, executes twice

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-notify

I'm using Gulp to compile stylus, but the task seems to run twice making `gulp-notify` trip.

**Here's my gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp, plugins;

gulp = require('gulp');
plugins = require('gulp-load-plugins')();


/**
 * Watch for changes on stylus files, when detecting change run stylus task
 * @return {void}
 */
gulp.task('watch-stylus', function() {
  gulp.src('./app/Resources/stylus/**/*.styl')
      .pipe(plugins.plumber())
      .pipe(plugins.watch('./app/Resources/stylus/**/*.styl', {
        verbose: true,
        readDelay: 0
      }))
      .pipe(plugins.exec('gulp stylus'))
      .pipe(plugins.notify("Stylus compiled"))
      .pipe(plugins.plumber.stop());
});

/**
 * Compile stylus and auto prefix the compiled css
 * @return {void}   
 */
gulp.task('stylus', function() {
  gulp.src(['./app/Resources/stylus/**/*.styl', '!./app/Resources/stylus/**/_*.styl'])
    .pipe(plugins.plumber())
    .pipe(plugins.stylus())
    .pipe(plugins.autoprefixer({
        browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
        cascade: false
      }))
    .pipe(plugins.plumber.stop())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('web/css'));
});
```

**Things I've checked**

- No multiple dests.
- Input and output dir are different.

**Image:**
[image: One file change]

**The plugins I'm using**

- `gulp-load-plugins` to load the plugins
- `gulp-watch` to watch for file changes
- `gulp-notify` to notify stylus has been compiled
- `gulp-stylus` to compile stylus
- `gulp-exec` to run compile task even when a partial was edited
- `gulp-autoprefixer` to prefix css
- `gulp-plumber` so `gulp-watch` doesn't die on error

Comment: you dont have `return` statement like `return gulp.src(`, that means gulp wont know when the task is finished, which might be causing this issue

Comment: Is Dropbox or similar thing open while working?